# how display.newImage() to image from another directory in lua - corona

Tags: lua, directory, coronasdk

I just want to clean my project directory of my corona project so i want to group it using directories. example for all the images, i have a `img` directory.

my project directory is in 
`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MyProject\img`

so in my code i do

`display.newImage("img.png",0,0,true)`

to

`display.newImage("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\MyProject\img\img.png",0,0,true)`

and

`display.newImage("img\img.png",0,0,true)`

but i got this error.

```
WARNING: Failed to find image(img.png)
```

my question is, how can i get the `img.png` from `img` directory using `display.newImage()`?
and how can i get the directory path on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the forward slash

```
display.newImage("img/img.png",0,0,true)
```